# How to add a piechart to a GUI?

Tags: python

I need to add a pie chart to a GUI, and my code is not in OOP format, and most of the tutorials I have seen are based on code in OOP format. Could someone let me know if they know a way I could solve this problem.

Comment: You will need to supply a LOT more detail for people to be able to help you. Please read the doc about asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: see this [tutorial](https://datatofish.com/how-to-create-a-gui-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

"OOP" format doesn't matter. Just use pygal:

http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/pie.html

```
pie_chart = pygal.Pie()
pie_chart.title = 'Browser usage in February 2012 (in %)'
pie_chart.add('IE', 19.5)
pie_chart.add('Firefox', 36.6)
pie_chart.add('Chrome', 36.3)
pie_chart.add('Safari', 4.5)
pie_chart.add('Opera', 2.3)
pie_chart.render()
```

The following are the output methods

http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/output.html